# using tmux and screen via ssh

Tags: macos, tmux, gnu-screen

I am using tmux on a local laptop to connect to a server via SSH in a pane. On that server, I am running several computations via screen.

The issue is that the server's screen key bindings such as C-A C-D to detach from session do not work now, probably because of local tmux.

Is there a way to tell local tmux to "ignore" key bindings for that particular pane?

EDIT: Following the suggested post in the comments, here is what helped me:
C-b C-a C-d
the first C-b is a local tmux binding, the next two are the remote screen's bindings.

Comment: Does the combination work when you connect without local `tmux`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, it does.

Comment: Thank you, it did help me find a solution, I will edit my original question to add the solution that helped me.